# list all users after filling in a form

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a event form for my members to fill in. The form is working and going to database.

But, how can I show which member has posted the event, so other people know? Because I tried having the `user_id` in sql string and was only showing the last post in the database not all posts from all users.

here is the form php section

```
<?php

include("config/db_connect.php");
include("config/ckh_session.php");


// Inserting user Details code
if (isset($_POST['btnSave'])) {
    $event_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_title']);
    $myDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myDate']);
    $cboStartTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cboStartTime']);
    $dteEndDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dteEndDate']);
    $dteEndTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dteEndTime']);
    $event_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_type']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
    $event_region = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_region']);
    $union_territory = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['union_territory']);
    $event_town = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_town']);
    $event_postalcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_postalcode']);
    $event_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_title']);
    $event_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_description']);
    $event_ltm = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_ltm']);


    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "update events set event_title = '" . $event_title . "' , 
myDate            = '" . $myDate . "' ,
cboStartTime      = '" . $cboStartTime . "' , 
dteEndDate        = '" . $dteEndDate . "' , 
dteEndTime        = '" . $dteEndTime . "' , 
event_type        = '" . $event_type . "' , 
country           = '" . $country . "' , 
event_region      = '" . $event_region . "' , 
union_territory   = '" . $union_territory . "' , 
event_town        = '" . $event_town . "' , 
event_postalcode  = '" . $event_postalcode . "' , 
event_title       = '" . $event_title . "' , 
event_description = '" . $event_description . "' , 
event_ltm         = '" . $event_ltm . "' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));


    if ($_POST['event_ltm'] == 'MF Cpl') {
        header("location: CoupleffEvent.php");
    } else if ($_POST['event_ltm'] == 'MM Cpl') {
        header("location: CouplemmEvent.php");
    } else if ($_POST['event_ltm'] == 'FF Cpl') {
        header("location: CoupleffEvent.php");
    }
}

// Fetch user details
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where user_id =  '" . $_SESSION['last_id'] . "' ");
$fetch_user = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$user_country = $fetch_user['user_country'];
$user_gender = $fetch_user['user_gender'];
?>
```

any help would be much appreciated so i can go to next step

Comment: please use prepared statements. Then there's also no need for mysqli_real_eascape

Comment: you mean like an activity log showing what each user posted?

Comment: yes thats it :)

Comment: @Jeff comment is really important and please consider it, in other words, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, don't concatenate data to your queries and use prepared statements instead.

Comment: ive looked into prepared statement and i dont understand it hun hence why used other

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` clause from your last `sql string`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're looking for.
If you're getting an user_id, you will have to select * FROM events and then join user table, like INNER JOIN user ON events.user_id = user.id

This type of request will display all event and join informations about the user.id

Resources : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/inner-join-with-multiple-tables.php

Hope it will help,